# I want to know the difference between DFA and FSA

Tags: finite-automata

Taking a class named Theory of Computation. Learned about Deterministic Finite Automata and just got introduced to Finite State Automata. I can't figure out the difference, are they just synonyms?

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/automata_theory/deterministic_finite_automaton.htm
[https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/introduction-of-finite-automata/#:~:text=The%20finite%20automata%20or%20finite,abstract%20model%20of%20digital%20computer](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/introduction-of-finite-automata/#:%7E:text=The%20finite%20automata%20or%20finite,abstract%20model%20of%20digital%20computer).

[image: Seems Like they are being used interchangeably]

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics.  You can [use LaTeX](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands).

Comment: @D.W. Understood.

Comment: I encourage you to [edit] your question to transcribe the text and mathematics in the image and replace the image with the transcription.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FSA just means "finite state automaton" and it doesn't specify whether we are talking about deterministic automata or non-determinsitic automata.

DFA is a shorthand for deterministic FSA. FSA and DFA can be used as synonyms if it is clear from the context that we are dealing with deterministic automata.